# left hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer?

Tags: c#, unityscript

Im making a simple pong game on Unity! This code seems to be giving me errors. Any idea what I could do to fix it?

```
if (gameObject.name == "Player1") {
        transform.Translate (0, Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") = speed, 0); 
    } else {
        transform.Translate (0, Input.GetAxis ("Vertical") = speed, 0);
    }
```

Comment: What is the error exactly? What `Translate` methods definition? What do you try to do with `Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") = speed` as a second parameter? Did you try to check their equality with `==` instead?

Comment: What are you doing here ``Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") = speed`` ??

Comment: you are using as a second parameter of Translate an assignment, which means nothing...look at the signature of the function

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (gameObject.name == "Player1") {
        transform.Translate (0, Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal"), 0); 
    } else {
        transform.Translate (0, Input.GetAxis ("Vertical"), 0);
    }
```